# element below transparent background element accesible in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transparency

I am trying to have a coverUp div eclipse another div below it. Then I am setting the coverUp's background as transparent. This makes the div below visible but the user cannot interact with it. Sadly this is not what happens in IE.

Once you set the coverUp div as transparent, the eclipsed div is accessible to the user in IE (including 10). Is there a solution for this?

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BKffG/).

```
<div class="coverUp"></div>
<div id="mapDiv"></div>

.coverUp {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

**EDIT**: Cannot use opacity as I have child elements in the coverUp Div, which fadeout when I apply opacity :0.

Comment: hey how it is possible if you cover it with a `div` then you can't handle `div's` underneath it. let me know what is the purpose of taking a `div` on the `mapdiv` to cover it.

Comment: The coverUp div in my App is meant to cover mapDiv but leave a little sliver at the end of about lets say 20px. I don't want the user to have access to the mapDiv through this sliver but I want the user to see the mapDiv below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this thanks to the [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/base64-encode-of-1x1px-transparent-gif/).

I added this,

```
background:url("datdata:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BKffG/1/).

**Note**: jsfiddle does not open in IE8 (atleast did not open for me in the IE8 mode in IE10 browser). So make this change in ur code and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transparent you can use opacity:0; this will still have the div as a block element.

Also you may want to set the z-index to 99999 to force it over top of every other element on the page.

Comment: Setting 99999 z-index does not work for IE. U can check it in the example in the question. also I have children in the coverUp Div, so setting opacity will also fade out the children

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css tag to make something transparent but with a background colour.

```
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

The first 3 arguments are hex numbers converted into decimal, the 4th is transparency. I don't know if it changes the opacity in the same way as setting `opacity: 0` or not, you may have to give it a go to find out, I don't know what else is supposed to be on the page.

I tested it in fiddler [(link)](http://jsfiddle.net/BKffG/3/) in IE9 but fiddler was having trouble loading the page in IE7 & 8, so I didn't test them unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work on IE8. The background color is white. It works fine on IE9 and IE10